# Container-fluid not working on Chrome and tablet-sized screen

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a header that covers the whole front page by using container-fluid. It works well on Opera, Firefox and Microsoft Edge, but on Chrome, iPad and mobile phone screens the header does not cover the whole device, it's shorter.

This is my code:

```
<div class="jumbotron2" id="top">
     <div class="container-fluid"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.jumbotron2 {
  background: url(../img/xx.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

.container-fluid {
       padding: 60px 50px;
}
```

What could I do to fix this?
Thank you.

EDIT:
Adding screen shots:

Chrome full screen laptop - background fills the whole screen

[chrome full screen laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcwwr.png)

Chrome small screen - tablet size
[chrome small screen tablet-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69aJu.png)

The smaller the screen, the bigger the white line above the header.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of the correct/incorrect page display?

Comment: Why have this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding given to `jumbotron`
also, if you want the `jumbotron` to fill entire screen, I would recommend following

```
.jumbotron2 {
  background: url(../img/xx.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem for Chrome but mobile and tablet screens now have a white line above the header (under the navbar).

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot? There might be something else interfering

Comment: You can provide any one or Both would do

Comment: Added screenshots. What other code should I post other than what I already posted? Sorry for stupid questions, this is my first attempt at a website, I'm doing all I can.

Comment: I would suggest you use a proper web server like apache or iis. Apache can be installed in a single bundled software called **wampserver** try loading files over that

Comment: Also try `background-size: cover` on jumbotron2 class

Comment: When I do that, there is a tiny white line on the left side of the screen. Since the background is dark, it is really visible. And it only extends along the header, the navbar stretches all the way across the top of the page (no white line there).

Comment: Must have been a glitch, the line is not there any more. But also realised that the header does not cover the screen in any browser, the other browsers were zoomed in, that's why it appeared as if it worked. Will go back to my code and look over it one more time to see if I can find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make the jumbotron `height: 100%;` so it fills the screen. Of course, this may distort the background image ratio.

http://www.bootply.com/z5XcRLL4O0

Comment: Thank you for the tip but it didn't change a thing, unfortunately.